# Can't open correctly .prn file from BarTender (TPCL)

Tags: printers, network-printers, bartender

I need to export a file from BarTender with Cyrillic, but when I open the file I get something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/keGJC.png

**Use next settings:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMPbe.png

Printer: TOSHIBA B-FV4

Answer (score 1):

Ok, when I use cyrillic, in text settings I use common font for cyrillic and thats correct write to .prn file.